# Query SQL based on records that does not exist

Tags: mysql

Having a problem to make this query work for a while now:

I have 3 tables:

```
table 1. projects
         -> id, name, ....

table 2. members
         -> user_id, project_id, ...

table 3. links
         -> user_id, project_id, is_binded
```

what i try to achieve:

Get all `projects.id` and `projects.name` from `projects`,
but only the projects coupled to a user (`members.user_id`)

AND where `is_binded` = false (but only the projects from the user)

OR

(this part i can't figure out) When there doesn't exist a record with the user_id, project_id and is_binded columns. So, when the project & user_id is not yet in the links table.

Basically, the query should return all projects from a user which are not binded or when there isn't a record of it in the links table.

The query is came up with:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM projects p 
JOIN links ml ON p.id = ml.project_id 
JOIN members m on p.id = m.project_id 
WHERE m.user_id = #{u_id} 
AND 
(ml.is_binded IS NULL OR (ml.is_binded = 0 AND ml.user_id = #{u_id}))
```

returns projects which are not in the table, but not on a user basis. when a record is in `links` with a `project_id` and `user_id`, i don't get a list with other `user_id`'s anymore. #{u_id} is a variable i use within ruby.

I hope my problem is a bit clear!

Comment: look at here :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, for SQL Server

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM    projects p
INNER JOIN  members m   ON m.project_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN   links   l   ON l.project_id = p.id and l.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE m.user_id = ?
 AND IFNULL(is_binded,'false') = 'false'
```

Comment: Looks like a nice route to test, but where do you specify the user_id. It should only return projects linked to a members.user_id

Comment: returns:  wrong syntax to use near 'is null(is_binded,'false') = 'false' Where m.user_id = 32 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5

Comment: Please check the modified answer, hope you are using sql server, both  mysql and sql-server  are tagged in this question.

Comment: i am only using mysql, i am sorry!

Comment: u can use IFNULL, instead of ISNULL in mysql, Query modified, plz chk. This is just a sample query logic to help u, bcs i don't hv your actual schema,datatype or data, you can modify this as per your requirement.

Comment: ifnull looks like its working. the results of your recent edit look good, testing them out right now!